# New to python! Can anyone explain why does this loop not work

Tags: python, loops

I want to iterate through the list test_board for each element and see whether it matches the value "X" or "O" if it does then the function should reproduce it as True,
else false.
But despite my changing the elements of the list the result nonetheless comes out as True.

```
test_board = ['#', 'X', 'L', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X']

def full_board_check(board):
    for i in range(1,10):
        if board[i] in ["X","O"]:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: For what input should this return False? Currently you check if any one element is X or O.

Comment: @luk2302 I think he is checking for incorrect inserted values into the list, such as any kind of character that is not `X` or `O`

Comment: @luk2302 when in input test_board in the function it shows True, no matter what is there in the list. I just don't get it!!!

Comment: Any reason why you start with the second element? You typically want to use `range(len(board))`

Comment: If you have only `L`s in the list it should return false. Why would you expect anything else, according to what logic?

Comment: @thinkgruen yes, i basically want to ignore the first value that is a hash as I am using this list to form a grid of 3x3 with values ranging from 1-9

Comment: @Cardstdani yes!!

Comment: @luk2302 that's exactly what I am talking about!! it should return false because of the L present in the list but it still shows the result as True

Comment: Not sure if I understand your requirement correctly, feel free to comment on my answer below. And you can accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: I also would like to suggest renaming the question to something more related to your question to generalize your question.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more idiomatic way:

```py
def full_board_check(board):
    return all(el in ["X", "O"] for el in board[1:])
```

`for el in board[1:]` will iterate over each element (not index) in the bord, starting with the second one. I usually prefer this iteration over `board[i]`, because you can pick a name, e.g. `for letter in "abc"`.

The rest is just list comprehension (I would recommend to give this concept a look) and then using `all` to validate your list of booleans.

Answer (score 2):

From this code, when there is a `"X"` or `"O"` it will return `True` instantly. But in your case, you want to check if there is something that doesn't match those two. You can switch the logic:

```
def full_board_check(board):
    for i in range(1,10):
        if board[i] not in ["X","O"]:
            return False
    return True
```

I'm assuming that you want to check whether the board is valid. In this code, it loops for each element, if there is something that is not `"X"` or `"O"`, it will return False. Otherwise, if it is still not returned yet, return True.

To make the code a little bit better, you can use the list element instead of the list index.

```
def full_board_check(board):
    for i, element in enumerate(board):
        if i == 0 and element != "#":
            return False
        elif element not in ["X","O"]:
            return False
    return True
```

Update: I added a condition to except `"#"` in first element.

Comment: @ Fony Lew Thanks a lot, man!! It worked, but the thing that I didn't understand is that doesn't for loop iterate through every element until the end of the range. like shouldn't it iterate through the test_board list for every element and if they are true it should then skip to the next element and check whether it fulfils the condition or not.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it solves your problem :D

Comment: Oh about your question, `return` means exiting the function and returning the result. In your code,  if any element `if` is satisfied, it will return `True` (and finish the function). Hence, it doesn't check for the rest, despite the correct range in `for`. That's why we use `return True` outside the `for` loop at the last to avoid early return.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check each element and get result for every of them you should use function like this:

```py
def full_board_check(board):
    result_list = []
    for element in board:
        if element not in ["X","O"]:
            result_list.append(False)
        else: result_list.append(True)
    return result_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reversed if condition and .find method. If any of given characters is not in the list ["X", "O"] then False - otherwise every element will be checked and if ok return True

```py
def full_board_check(board=['A', 'X', 'L', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X']):
    for i in range(len(board)):
        if 'X, O'.find(board[i]) == 0:
            return False

    return True
```